# Bootstrap carousel - JavaScript not applying (DNN)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, dotnetnuke

Let me start by saying I have almost no understanding of JavaScript.

I have a Bootstrap (3) carousel, which contains images and text, of different quantities. When the carousel animates, all content below the carousel jumps as the carousel resizes its height according to the height of the content.

I have followed http://ryanringler.com/blog/2014/08/24/fixed-height-carousel-for-twitter-bootstrap which is designed to calculate the maximum height of the content within the carousel, and apply to each slide - preventing the jump of page content below the carousel. This has almost fixed the problem, but not quite.

It seems the javascript only applies after I resize the browser window. Having basically no understanding of how JS works, I was hoping there is a simple solution to this that someone might be able to help me with? I would be eternally greatful!

I have the following loaded in the Page Header Tags section of Page Settings > Advanced Settings in DNN.

```
window.onload = function() {
  carouselNormalization();
}
```

I have the following loaded within script tags in an html module on the page:

```
function carouselNormalization() {
  var items   = $('#carousel-reviews .item'),              // grab all the slides
      heights = [],                                   // array to store heights
      tallest;                                        // tallest slide

  if (items.length) {
    function normalizeHeights() {
      items.each(function() {
        heights.push($(this).height());               // add each slide's height
      });                                             // to the array

      tallest = Math.max.apply(null, heights);        // find the largest height

      items.each(function() {
        $(this).css('min-height', tallest + 'px');    // set each slide's minimum
      });                                             // height to the largest
    };

    normalizeHeights();

    $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
      tallest = 0, heights.length = 0;               // reset the variables

      items.each(function() {
        $(this).css('min-height', '0');              // reset each slide's height
      });

      normalizeHeights();                            // run it again
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the page: http://mystate.com.au/about-us/contact-us/locations/launceston-branch

I have also noticed that sometimes the JS does apply if I press the scroll button immediately after page load, but if I wait a few seconds, it seems it doesn't.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome console says: `carouFredSel: No element found for "#carousel_2item"` and also for `#carousel_4item`. You should probably fix that first.

Also the id `carousel-id` does not exist on your site. You probably need to replace that with the ID of your actual element. (try `carousel-reviews`)

Comment: Thanks, it actually is carousel-reviews - I accidentally  copied and pasted the wrong code sorry. Have edited my post. Any idea how to make sure the script runs properly?

Comment: Yes it does, but with different content creating different heights for the carousel, it means the content below jumps when the carousel resizes.

Comment: Why not set the parent height of the parent `<div>` manually? Then you don't need that piece of code. Al tough it does seem to work on FireFox, but only then the carousel is visible, then you see it jump to a larger format after 1s the first time it is in the viewport.

Comment: I have several similar pages, all with the same issue, which is why I'm trying an automated/JS approach. I can achieve the desired solution using media queries if needs be but that is more manual work. I thought it'd be something simple to do with where I have the JS code or how it is being called... Thanks for your suggestions anyway.